# Cannot load a library into pyinstaller

Tags: python, cryptography, python-3.6, pyinstaller, scrypt

#### Problem

I've been trying to build a fairly large python application into an executable for windows. I've done a mac build which works fine but I seem to be stuck loading in the _scrypt .pyd file that the scrypt 
module trys to load in at runtime.

```
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 
'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\Application\\dist\\test\\_scrypt.cp36- 
win_amd64.pyd'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the 
application was frozen.
```

#### I have tried the following:

- Defining the scrypt .pyd file under binaries and hidden imports in my spec file. This works fine for all other files i need to add.
- Using a runtime hook.
- Using any other available python freeze application.
- Editing the scrypts code.
- Downloading up to SSL certificates 1.1.
- Reinstalling microsoft .dlls i may be missing.
- Reinstalling both the scrypt module and pycryptodome modules.

Running `import scrypt` into the python terminal gives me`OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`, although strangely running the program i'm trying to build works until trying to use pyinstaller.

#### Relevant code in the scrypt module

```
import imp
import os
import sys

from ctypes import (cdll,
                    POINTER, pointer,
                    c_char_p,
                    c_size_t, c_double, c_int, c_uint64, c_uint32,
                    create_string_buffer)

__version__ = '0.8.6'

_scrypt = cdll.LoadLibrary(imp.find_module('_scrypt')[1])
#_scrypt = cdll.LoadLibrary("_scrypt.cp36-win_amd64.pyd")
```

Would really appreciate any advice where to go next, thank you.

Comment: Is `_scrypt.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` in `C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Application\dist\test\`?

Comment: Yeah, ```OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found``` i'm getting that when i try ```import scrypt``` into python terminal, although strangely running the program works without trying to build it with pyinstaller.